# Text to Speech destroyed before completion in IntentService

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-activity

I have an IntentService that speaks out using TTS when a user enter certain geographical area(using Geofence). Since it is IntentService, many times the IntentService is destroyed even before it could speak out name of the place. What should I do to ensure it speaks completely and then destroyes IntentService? My code looks like this:

```
public class GeofenceIntentService extends IntentService implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    private TextToSpeech engine;

    public GeofenceIntentService() {
        super("GeofenceIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int Status) {
        if (Status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            engine.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        engine = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        while  (engine.isSpeaking()) {
            System.out.println("Hey engine is still speaking...");
        }
        super.onDestroy();
        engine.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (!geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            int transition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
            String notificationTitle;
            switch (transition) {
                case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                    notificationTitle = "Geofence Entered";
                    Log.v(TAG, "Geofence Entered");
                    break;
                default:
                    notificationTitle = "Geofence Unknown";
            }

            sendNotification(this, getTriggeringGeofences(intent), notificationTitle);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void sendNotification(Context context, String notificationText,
                                  String notificationTitle) {
            engine.speak("You are approaching Bus Stop " + notificationText,
                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
        }

    private String getTriggeringGeofences(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofenceEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        List<Geofence> geofences = geofenceEvent
                .getTriggeringGeofences();

        String[] geofenceIds = new String[geofences.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < geofences.size(); i++) {
            geofenceIds[i] = geofences.get(i).getRequestId();
        }

        return TextUtils.join(", ", geofenceIds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `IntentService`. Use your own `Service` with your own background thread. When you find out that the TTS has completed, call `stopSelf()` on the `Service`. I haven't used the TTS APIs, so I don't know if/how you find out when the utterance is finished.

Comment: @CommonsWare When I change my IntentService to Service, it is not called at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, there is no `onHandleIntent()` method on `Service`. You need to fork your own thread from `onStartCommand()` that does the work presently in `onHandleIntent()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. Do you have a link that I can read to understand how to convert this to Service instead of IntentService. Sorry, I am pretty new to Android. Trying to follow an example.

Comment: Nothing handy, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare I had a similar problem which I never got the solution for... Could it be the same reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908881/how-can-i-fix-my-audio-prioritize